# Stripe not working with live publishableKey React Native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

In my Stripeprovider in App.js I was using the publishable test key with no issues everything was working pretty well, when I changed it to the live key stripe ( I also changed the secret on the backend) loads for split second then closes without any intent made on stripe dashboard.

```
<StripeProvider
  publishableKey={secret}
  ...
>
.
.
.
</StripeProvider>
```

Comment: It's really hard to help with so little info. maybe you could edit your question and add more context, share some code, etc. Otherwise I would recommend either contacting support directly on Discord https://discord.com/invite/stripe or via the support chat https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

Comment: Have you changed both the secret and the public keys for live mode?

Comment: @Tarzan yes I did

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to follow these steps in order to go live if you are willing to use Google Pay:
https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=react-native#going-live-react-native

Comment: I didn't mention google pay, my problem is live credential key are not working while test keys are

Comment: Could you please share more details, how are you integrating Stripe ? Are you targeting the Android or iOS platform ? What Stripe element are you using? How are you creating the payment intent? Is it from your mobile application or backend ?

Answer (score 0):

try this step

1. Be sur the publishable key is in your front and you secret key in your back.
2. Be sur you use the compatible key ( pk_test_XXX front & sk_test_XXX back) OR ( pk_live_XXX front & sk_live_XXX back)
3. Be sur you return the good things from your endpoints

In my case, what i did wrong, i returned the wrong publishableKey from the back.

I'm using the Composant Element & the hooks

```
const {initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet} = useStripe();
```

You have the documentation from stripe of what you need to return from the back here

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet